# Docker FROM instruction not found in dockertoolbox

Tags: docker

Im a newbie to docker and trying to get my hands dirty. I installed docker toolbox in my windows laptop and trying to create a docker image from docker terminal.

This is the command i run - "FROM microsoft/aspnet" and the error message i get is "bash: FROM: command not found".

Any pointers on what could be wrong will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FROM command has to be put in a file called Dockerfile

Then, you can build your docker image using

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

Anyway, a custom docker Image built using a FROM command only is pointless.

I suggest you to read the docker getting started page: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/